# How to use Spring Data JPA with MultiTenant different database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to implement Spring Data JPA with MultiTenant using different databases(Postgresql, Oracle, Mysql) but couldn't find a simple way of doing that, all samples that I found was using one database only.

I did a workaround to set a dynamic entityManager by reflection but I believe that's not the right way, maybe somehow is that possible to create multiple spring data contexts for each database then change at runtime?

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public class CustomRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements BaseRepository<T, ID> {
    public static MultiTenantEntityManagerFactoryBean multiTenantEntityManagerFactoryBean;

    public CustomRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);

        log.info("Using custom repository");
    }

    //TODO Very ugly workaround need to find a better way to set entityManager.
    private void setDynamicEntityManager() {
        Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(this.getClass(), "em");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        EntityManager entityManager = multiTenantEntityManagerFactoryBean.getEntityManagerInterface();
        ReflectionUtils.setField(field, this, entityManager);
        log.info("setDynamicEntityManager:entityManagerAfter: {}", entityManager);
    }

    //TODO Need to override all methods from SimpleJpaRepository.
    @Override
    public Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        log.info("findlAll: {}", pageable);
        setDynamicEntityManager();
        return super.findAll(pageable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you looking to do? If you want to choose a database dynamically based on each request, Spring Data can’t do that.

Comment: Hi @AbhijitSarkar, yes that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve, this works fine if I don't have a query that uses specific commands like the ones for pagination(with Pageable). A simple crud query would work fine, if you want to take a look in the code for more details please look at https://github.com/rodrigorodrigues/springboot-multitenant-hibernate

Answer (score -2):

You have multiple databases, so you need to declare multiple data sources in the Spring Boot application.properties file.

```
   #----- tenant 1


    name=tenant_1
    datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tenant1
    datasource.username=postgres
    datasource.password=123456
    datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

    #----- tenant 2


    name=tenant_2
    datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tenant2
    datasource.username=postgres
    datasource.password=123456
    datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Then create separate datasource(s), separate them using @ConfigureProperties(prefix="tenant" //pass the identifier of the respective database configuration.

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "tenants")
public DataSource dataSource() {
...
...}
```

You would need to use DAO pattern to handle multiple databases. Inject them here. Hope this helps.

Comment: OP mentioned using a hack so their problem is not configuring multiple data sources.